# Quitar extensión .php con htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess

Necesito quitar las extensiones de los archivos .html y .php, con .html me funciona correctamente pero con las extensiones .php no está funcionando, me da error 404 os dejo mi .htaccess

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://miweb.com/$1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.php [NC]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/?$ $1.html [NC]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que no tengas habilitado el mod_rewrite en el servidor. Si estas en Apache prueba con esto:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite

sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Buscar y Descomentar la línea `AccessFileName .htaccess` (remueve el símbolo #)

Luego de salir y guardar los cambios de Nano debes recargar apache.

```
sudo service apache2 reload
```